# Delete all lines which contain any word not used anywhere else in the buffer

Tags: search

**Note**: For those of you who do not know VHDL do not worry, I will explain the problem with an example.

## Motivation

I have a VHDL file which is a big mess of buses. I have declared many `signals` and I think I have some unused signals. I want to delete unnecessary declarations.

## Example

Imagine I have the following signal declarations

```
signal exmem_wb_we_in : std_logic;
signal exmem_const_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal exmem_data_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal exmem_addr_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal exmem_foo_in : std_logic;
signal exmem_mem_en_in : std_logic;
signal exmem_bar_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal exmem_jump_cond_in : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
```

Say the signals in bold (`exmem_foo_in` and `exmem_bar_in`) are never used. Then those words occur only once in the file. I want the lines where they appear to be deleted.

## The question

Is it possible to get Vim to delete all lines which hold a single occurrence of a word in a file? The solution should use Vim commands that are 'always available', rather than OS dependent commands. A single command would be preferred. But multiple commands are also welcome.

#### Some assumptions

- assume only one signal is declared per line;
- there are no occurrences of numbers who appear only once in the file and could get us a line deleted when we in fact want that line;
- there are no comments which introduce a single word occurrence.

Bonus points if you can make it still work without some of those assumptions.

**Clarifications**:

- I don't know which words I want to delete beforehand.
- A VHDL file might look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxbPA.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Can you please clarify, so, the goal is to delete all lines containing unique words? Without knowing beforehandedly what are these unique words?

Comment: @shabunc, yes, that is the situation.

Comment: @IngoKarkat I haven't. I normally would (I know how SE works ;) ) but in this case I have no feeling at all on how I could achieve this. The only thing that occurs to me is searching and counting. But since I don't know the words I want to search beforehand I really don't know where to start...

Comment: Do you require a single command that carries out the entire process? Or are you just looking to get the job done?

Comment: @Rich, a single command would be preferred. But multiple commands are also welcome.

Comment: @Rich, I think "delete all lines which contain any unique words" is the right question to think about. So that the answer can be useful in other situations. But for more general cases it could be useful to put restrictions like "if the unique word is a number do not delete the line".

Comment: I think the mistake that I (and shabunc, below) was making is that we thought that *all* the lines in the file conformed to the format described in your code sample, whereas now I'm guessing that the *rest* of the file is completely different?

Comment: @Rich yes, the rest of the file is completely different. I edited my question to provide an example file. Thank you for your edit, btw.

Comment: Is there a reason this must be done in vim commands rather than, say, an external script that could be run on the file? It feels like the problem might be easier to approach from the outside.

Comment: @SnoringFrog, I have two reasons: 1) achieving OS independence for the task (on Linux a script for this would be easy, but not on Windows, I think); 2) exploring the limits of Vim.

Comment: In your sample file, a completely generic solution might also delete the last line, which contains a unique `3`. I bring this up because I feel the problem is too delicate for a general solution.

Comment: Typically simulators provide a linting option that reports unused declared signals. What I do is to copy that list to the file and then record a macro that searches the signal under the cursor, deletes the line, searches again and deletes line again (the original one where we started). I then just repeat the macro the required number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Just to delete all lines containing some specific word you can by just typing:

```
:g/exmem_bar_in/d
:g/exmem_foo_in/d
```

The signature is

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
```

(can be found by :h :g)

If you need to know the list of unique words, it actually heavily depends on what you indeed want to treat as a unique word. I doubt that you actually mean any unique word but rather something unique in the signal section. If it is so, then I'd just create a separate buffer, copied eveything there, then
remove all besides "signal :" prefix:

```
:%s/\(.*\):.*/\1/ "deleting all after last semicolon
```

then leave only unique value:

```
:sort u.
```

Now I have a list of unique words I can work with.

Comment: That doesn't address what the OP is asking, though.

Comment: @jamessan re-read the question and still don't get - so, the goal is to delete all lines containing unique words?

Comment: The goal is to delete a line if that is the only line in the file containing a certain word.

Comment: @jamessan I'm not arguing, I'm just trying to understand the question better to asnwer it neverthelees. "The only line in file containing a certain word" - but it looks like :g/<pattern>/d  falls under this definition

Comment: The OP doesn't know what words need to be deleted.  So the goal is to have a way to run a command which will determine which of a set of words only appear in one line and then delete those lines.  `:g/{pattern}/d` only solves the second part of the problem, not the first.

Comment: @jamessan in that case the definition of unique word should be clarified by OP, because, for instance, any line with number occured once ("3 downto 0" in the example whould be deleted as well